# SessionFactory и Hibernate 4

Tags: hibernate, java

Как правильно создавать фабрику используя Hibernate 4? 
Этот метод не подходит -

```
 sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().bu​ildSessionFactory();
```

ведь - "buildSessionFactory()" - теперь deprecated.... 
 Кто-нибудь может привети рабочий пример класса HibernateUtils?? 
 Буду благодарен ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь следующим сниппетом (теперь используется `ServiceRegistry`):

```
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

private static SessionFactory configureSessionFactory() throws HibernateException {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure();
    serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder()
        .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
        .buildServiceRegistry();

    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

    return sessionFactory;
}
```

Comment: спасибо, попробовал, у меня, видимо, ещё в чём-то проблема, выдаёт ошибку
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/transaction/SystemException
ругается на эту строчку  
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

Comment: поборол эту ошибку))
надо было из зависимостей мавена убрать 
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <<artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
ещё раз благодарю за этот сниппет! ;)