# SessionFactory в Hibernate 4 для чайников

Tags: java, hibernate

Пытаюсь разобратся в Hibernate, а именно в SessionFactory.
Вот прочитал ответ по поводу создания сесии (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/85082/198514):

```
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

private static SessionFactory configureSessionFactory() throws HibernateException {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure();
    serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder()
        .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
        .buildServiceRegistry();

    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

    return sessionFactory;
}
```

Так мне ответили на https://forum.hibernate.org:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().addProperties(properties);
SessionFactory sf = configuration.buildSessionFactory(
    new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
        .applySettings(properties)
        .build()
);
```

А вот так мне показывали:

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder sb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
            sb.applySettings(cfg.getProperties());
            StandardServiceRegistry standardServiceRegistry = sb.build();

            return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory(standardServiceRegistry);
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }
```

Если найдется человек, который объяснит разницу между подходами и что делает каждый метод, буду очень признателен.

**Обновление**

В первом варианте я не понимаю, где добавляются параметры конфигурации? А во втором не разобрался, как именно задаются properties. Я так понимаю `new Configuration().addProperties(properties)`, идентично `new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")`

Если я не прав поправьте: сначала `Properties properties = new Properties();`. А потом нужно методом `put()` добавлять разные свойства.

Comment: Во всех случаях SessionFactory строится в три шага. 1) Тем или иным способом получить Configuration. 2) По Configuration построить StandardServiceRegistry с помощью StandardServiceRegistryBuilder-а. 3) По StandardServiceRegistry построить SessionFactory с помощью Configuration. В последнем случае вероятно ошибка. Вместо `return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory(standardServiceRegistry);` наверно надо было написать `return cfg.buildSessionFactory(standardServiceRegistry);`

Comment: @АлександрТищенко `new Configuration().addProperties(properties)` не идентично `new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")`

Comment: @Sergey Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Comment: мне помогло создание пользователя БД для приложения.

Answer (score 11):

**Первый подход**

```
private static SessionFactory configureSessionFactory() throws HibernateException {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure();
    serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder()
        .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
        .buildServiceRegistry();

    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

    return sessionFactory;
}
```

Зачитывает конфигурацию из `hibernate.cfg.xml` и `hibernate.properties`.
Должен работать во всех подверсиях Hibernate 4 правильно.

`hibernate.cfg.xml` зачитывается здесь `configuration.configure()`

Вот это `applySettings(configuration.getProperties())` необходимо, чтобы не потерять properties из `hibernate.cfg.xml` (в этом файле можно указывать свойства так же, как в `hibernate.properties`). Например, если у Вас там свойства не указаны (а обычно они там не указываются), то достаточно вот этого

```
return new Configuration().configure().
    buildSessionFactory(new ServiceRegistryBuilder().buildServiceRegistry());
```

Вообще, эта некрасивая возня с `ServiceRegistryBuilder` из-за того, что дополнительный тюнинг конфигурации вынесли в отдельный класс, а`buildSessionFactory()` опрометчиво сделали `@Deprecated`.

В Hibernate 5 вообще хотели выбросить класс `Configuration` и перейти к конфигурированию с использованием `StandardServiceRegistryBuilder` и `MetadataSources`. Из javadocs [Configuration Hibernate 4.3](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/)

> NOTE : This will be replaced by use of StandardServiceRegistryBuilder
>   and MetadataSources instead after the 4.0 release at which point this
>   class will become deprecated and scheduled for removal in 5.0. See
>   HHH-6183, HHH-2578 and HHH-6586 for details

Далее, в Hibernate 5, судя по всему, от этой идеи отказались и данного замечания в документации к `Configuraton` нет.

`hibernate.properties` зачитываются извращенным образом в статическом инициализаторе класса [Environment](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.10.Final/org/hibernate/cfg/Environment.java?av=f#206). То есть, при первом обращении к нему. Это, скорее всего, происходит здесь `new Configuration()`.

**Второй подход**

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().addProperties(properties);
SessionFactory sf = configuration.buildSessionFactory(
    new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
        .applySettings(properties)
        .build()
);
```

Будет работать только начиная с версии Hibernate 4.3, так как только начиная с этой версии присутствует класс `StandardServiceRegistryBuilder`. Вы можете считать, что `StandardServiceRegistryBuilder` — это тоже самое, что и `ServiceRegistryBuilder`. Начиная с версии 4.3 `ServiceRegistryBuilder` был помечен, как `@Deprecated`, а все его содержимое было скопировано в `StandardServiceRegistryBuilder`.

Так как здесь

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().addProperties(properties);
```

метод `configure()` не вызывается, то соответственно, информация о маппинге из файла `hibernate.cfg.xml` зачитываться не будет. Вообще, этот подход можно рассматривать как неполный вариант третьего подхода.

**Третий подход**

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder sb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
    sb.applySettings(cfg.getProperties());
    StandardServiceRegistry standardServiceRegistry = sb.build();

    return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory(standardServiceRegistry);
```

Этот подход будет работать правильно начиная с версии Hibernate 4.3 (из-за уже упомянутого `StandardServiceRegistryBuilder`). Но он содержит избыточность, о которой упомянул @Sergey. Если убрать избыточность, то этот вариант сведется к

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure();
StandardServiceRegistryBuilder sb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
sb.applySettings(cfg.getProperties());
StandardServiceRegistry standardServiceRegistry = sb.build();

return сfg.buildSessionFactory(standardServiceRegistry);
```

Что является тем же самым, что первый подход, так как `StandardServiceRegistryBuilder` — это тоже самое, что и `ServiceRegistryBuilder`.

**Как делать правильнее всего**

Правильнее всего делать вот так

```
return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

Основная причина, на мой взгляд, это то что все вышеперичисленные подходы на будут вообще (!) правильно работать с Hibernate 5. Об этом [подробнее можно почитать здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32711654/3405171).

Хотя `buildSessionFactory()` объявлена как `@Deprecated` в Hibernate 4, в Hibernate 5 она запилена обратно! Соответственно, вышеприведенный код будет правильно работать во всех версиях Hibernate.

**Указание путей к файлам конфигурации**

Об этом я подробно написал здесь:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/518090/199368