# Структура Web приложения Java + Hibernate без Spring

Tags: java, веб-программирование, hibernate, tomcat

Я пытаюсь разобраться с веб-приложением java.

Использую Intellij IDEA

Сначала я написал маленькое консольное приложение, в котором шло обращение к базе, выборка данных и вывод результата в консоль. Сначала сделал через JDBC потом переделал через Hibernate

Потом я решил переделать его в веб-приложение, создал Maven-овский веб-проект и закинул в папку `java` пакеты `HiberUtil` и класс `Main`, а в `resources` положил xml-файлы конфигов хибера. Т.е. я просто закинул файлы консольного приложения как были в предыдущем проекте.

Подключил Tomcat к Идее, написал сервлеты, jsp. Получилась следующая структура:

[image: структура проекта]

Проблема в том, что не хибер не подхватывает конфиги в `configure()`

[image: сообщение Tomcat]

Закинув файл `hibernate.cfg.xml` в `webapp` хибер заводится, но не подхватывает конфиги для классов. Соответсвенно, если скопировать конфиги классов, то не подхватываются сами классы.

Переписав все обратно через JDBC получаю рабочее приложение.

Объясните, пожалуйста, как правильно должны располагаться файлы или где почитать о структуре проекта

**Update**

```
"C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.0.33\bin\catalina.bat" run
[2016-04-29 11:39:48,307] Artifact test2LSwebapp:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\emina\.IntelliJIdea15\system\tomcat\Unnamed_test2LSwebapp_2"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.0.33"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.0.33\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.0.33\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.0.33\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
29-Apr-2016 11:39:50.769 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.33
29-Apr-2016 11:39:50.772 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Mar 18 2016 20:31:49 UTC
29-Apr-2016 11:39:50.772 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.33.0
29-Apr-2016 11:39:50.772 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
29-Apr-2016 11:39:50.772 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
29-Apr-2016 11:39:50.772 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
29-Apr-2016 11:39:50.772 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre
29-Apr-2016 11:39:50.775 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_77-b03
29-Apr-2016 11:39:50.775 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
29-Apr-2016 11:39:50.776 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\emina\.IntelliJIdea15\system\tomcat\Unnamed_test2LSwebapp_2
29-Apr-2016 11:39:50.776 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.0.33
29-Apr-2016 11:39:50.776 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
29-Apr-2016 11:39:50.777 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
29-Apr-2016 11:39:50.777 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
29-Apr-2016 11:39:50.777 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
29-Apr-2016 11:39:50.777 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
29-Apr-2016 11:39:50.777 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\emina\.IntelliJIdea15\system\tomcat\Unnamed_test2LSwebapp_2\conf\logging.properties
29-Apr-2016 11:39:50.777 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
29-Apr-2016 11:39:50.777 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.0.33\endorsed
29-Apr-2016 11:39:50.777 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\emina\.IntelliJIdea15\system\tomcat\Unnamed_test2LSwebapp_2
29-Apr-2016 11:39:50.778 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.0.33
29-Apr-2016 11:39:50.778 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.0.33\temp
29-Apr-2016 11:39:50.778 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.2.5 using APR version 1.5.1.
29-Apr-2016 11:39:50.779 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
29-Apr-2016 11:39:51.829 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016)
29-Apr-2016 11:39:52.124 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
29-Apr-2016 11:39:52.177 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
29-Apr-2016 11:39:52.180 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 2049 ms
29-Apr-2016 11:39:52.228 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
29-Apr-2016 11:39:52.228 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.33
29-Apr-2016 11:39:52.241 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
29-Apr-2016 11:39:52.254 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
29-Apr-2016 11:39:52.257 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 76 ms
Connected to server
[2016-04-29 11:39:52,697] Artifact test2LSwebapp:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
29-Apr-2016 11:39:54.558 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
[2016-04-29 11:39:54,670] Artifact test2LSwebapp:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2016-04-29 11:39:54,670] Artifact test2LSwebapp:war exploded: Deploy took 1 973 milliseconds
29-Apr-2016 11:40:02.264 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.0.33\webapps\manager
29-Apr-2016 11:40:02.350 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.0.33\webapps\manager has finished in 85 ms
29-Apr-2016 11:40:13.911 INFO [http-apr-8080-exec-10] org.hibernate.Version.logVersion HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.1.0.Final}
29-Apr-2016 11:40:13.915 INFO [http-apr-8080-exec-10] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.<clinit> HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
29-Apr-2016 11:40:13.918 INFO [http-apr-8080-exec-10] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.buildBytecodeProvider HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
29-Apr-2016 11:40:14.727 INFO [http-apr-8080-exec-10] org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.<clinit> HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
29-Apr-2016 11:40:16.545 WARN [http-apr-8080-exec-10] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
29-Apr-2016 11:40:16.560 INFO [http-apr-8080-exec-10] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator HHH10001005: using driver [org.h2.Driver] at URL [jdbc:h2:~/test]
29-Apr-2016 11:40:16.560 INFO [http-apr-8080-exec-10] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=sa, password=****}
29-Apr-2016 11:40:16.561 INFO [http-apr-8080-exec-10] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
29-Apr-2016 11:40:16.569 INFO [http-apr-8080-exec-10] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init> HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
29-Apr-2016 11:40:17.578 INFO [http-apr-8080-exec-10] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.<init> HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
29-Apr-2016 11:40:19.848 INFO [http-apr-8080-exec-10] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.stop HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:h2:~/test]
```

запустил `install` в Maven-е, получил war-файл, зашел в него:
[image: war-файл]

обновил свой проект и исправил имена конфигов[image: обновление]

`HiberUtil.java`

package HibernateUtils;

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HiberUtil {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;

        static {
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Comment: Стоит покурить мануалы гиберната.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> проблема в том, что не хибер не подхватывает конфиги в configure()

Та ошибка, которая на скриншоте, не имеет отношения к конфигурированию, так как эта ошибка возникает на этапе выполнения запроса к базе. Пожалуйста, в следующий раз приводите полный стектрейс, а не скриншот.

По поводу расположения файлов. Когда вы делаете `new Configuration().configure()` Hibernate пытается загрузить `hibernate.cfg.xml` через `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(resourcePath)` 
`resourcePath` — это путь к ресурсу.

Если упрощенно (не рассматривая полный classpath), то в web-приложении класслоадер пытается получить доступ к файлу из `war/WEB-INF/classes`.
Например:

`configure("hibernate.cfg.xml") — war/WEB-INF/classes/hibernate.cfg.xml`
`configure("xxx/hibernate.cfg.xml") — war/WEB-INF/classes/xxx/hibernate.cfg.xml`

Те файлы, на которые ссылается `hibernate.cfg.xml` (ваши конфиги для классов), тоже загружаются класслоадером, по тем же правилам (принято давать им постфикс `hbm.xml`)

```
<mapping resource="hibernate/fileStatistic.hbm.xml"></mapping>
```

соответствует `war/WEB-INF/classes/hibernate/fileStatistic.hbm.xml`

Интересно, что для класслоадера путь к файлу не должен начинаться с `/`, но Hibernate учитывает это и пытается удалять лидирующий `/` при неудачной загрузке, поэтому путь `/hibernate/fileStatistic.hbm.xml`, тоже является корректным.

Если Вы используете сборку Maven, то для консольного приложения Maven помещает содержимое `resources` туда же, куда помещает откомпилированное содержимое папки `src` — в корень папки `bin` или `build`, или в корень `jar`. Для web-приложения, Maven помещает содержимое `resources` в `war/WEB-INF/classes`. Если все правильно настроено. Поэтому Вам надо посмотреть в `war`, что у Вас содержится в `war/WEB-INF/classes`.

Вот метод, который загружает ресурсы в Hibernate

```
public InputStream locateResourceStream(String name) {
    // first we try name as a URL
    try {
        return new URL( name ).openStream();
    }
    catch (Exception ignore) {
    }

    try {
        final InputStream stream = getAggregatedClassLoader().getResourceAsStream( name );
        if ( stream != null ) {
            return stream;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ignore) {
    }

    final String stripped = name.startsWith( "/" ) ? name.substring( 1 ) : null;

    if ( stripped != null ) {
        try {
            return new URL( stripped ).openStream();
        }
        catch (Exception ignore) {
        }

        try {
            final InputStream stream = getAggregatedClassLoader().getResourceAsStream( stripped );
            if ( stream != null ) {
                return stream;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ignore) {
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

**Update**

В `war` не должно быть папки `resources`, или Вам надо будет ее указывать в путях к файлам конфигурации.

Вы можете проверить доступен ли файл маппинга (или `hibernate.cfg.xml`), выполнив следующий код до того, как происходит ошибка

```
URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
    .getResource(
    "hibernate/fileStatistic.cfg.xml");
System.out.println(url);
```

**Update 2**

Судя по всему, Hibernate находит файлы конфигурации. Ошибка, которая на скриншоте происходит из-за `sessionFactory.close()` эту строку надо удалить.
Вам надо добавить логирование, чтобы понимать что происходит.
Добавьте в `pom.xml`

```
<dependency> 
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.21</version>
</dependency>
```

Включите логирование SQL в Hibernate, и поместите файл `log4j.properties` рядом с `hibernate.cfg.xml`. Включите создание схемы, чтобы посмотреть как отмапились таблицы

```
<property name = "hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

Я еще вот такое добавил, будет работать только при пересоздании схемы

```
session.beginTransaction();

FileStatistic st = new FileStatistic();
st.setIdFile(1);

session.save(st);
session.flush();

Criteria criteriaFile = session.createCriteria(FileStatistic.class);
fileStatistic = criteriaFile.list();

session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: Попробовал собрать Maven-ом, выдал ошибку несовместимости компилятора с try-with-resources. Поправил pom-файл, чтобы собирался в версии 1.8, все прошло без ошибок. Проверил war-файл, файлы лежал по папкам как в исходнике. Xml-файлы для классов лежат в той же папке что и сами классы

Comment: @Prahvessor Пожалуйста, добавьте примеры путей в war и полный stack trace ошибки в вопрос.

Comment: я обновил вопрос

Comment: @Prahvessor В `hibernate.cfg.xml` пути к `hbm.xml` должны быть `StatisticBeans/fileStatistic.hbm.xml`. A где `hibernate.cfg.xml` оказался?

Comment: он на уровень выше, в нем прописано  `<mapping resource="StatisticBeans/fileStatistic.hbm.xml"/>  
        <mapping resource="StatisticBeans/lineStatistic.hbm.xml"/>`

Comment: @Prahvessor Добавьте, пожалуйста код `HiberUtil`

Comment: добавил `HiberUtil`, обновил вопрос

Comment: @Prahvessor Ошибок я не вижу. Может русская буква в имени `hibernate.cfg.xml`. А что выдает код получения `url` для `hibernate.cfg.xml`?

Comment: @Prahvessor Да и все-таки лог  ошибки со скриншота неплохо бы добавить.

Comment: `https://prahvessor@bitbucket.org/prahvessor/test2lswebapp` - это репозиторий, в нем исходники, может так проще будет найти ошибку?

Comment: @Prahvessor Я обновил

Comment: убрал ` sessionFactory.close() ` и все заработало! спасибо! я чуть голову себе не расплавил из-за этого! Если Вам не трудно, объясните еще почему или киньте в меня ссылкой. Очень бы хотелось с этим разобраться

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39112/discussion-between-prahvessor-and-v-ladynev).